# #ifdef SIOCSHWTSTAMP not found

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, timestamp, network-programming

I want to take hardware timestamps on the network card. I found some example code from Solarflare which checks whether the following label is defined:

```
#ifdef SIOCSHWTSTAMP
    struct ifreq ifr;
    struct hwtstamp_config hwc;
#else
    static_assert(false);         // I added this to check whether my system has the label defined
#endif
```

but the `static_assert` is getting triggered, so this label is not defined in my system.

I am including these headers:

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <net/if.h>
```

so clearly it's not defined in those.

We installed `linux-libc-dev` but it doesn't seem to have helped.

Which header should it exist in, so I can check?

My kernel version is 3.10.0-1062.4.1.el7.x86_64 and CentOS 7

Comment: In newer kernels it's in *include/uapi/linux/sockios.h* In 3.10 it's there as well: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/ident/SIOCSHWTSTAMP

Comment: @0andriy thanks, including that worked! If you put it as an answer i'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Linux OS it's defined in the User API kernel headers, i.e. in the 
[include/uapi/linux/sockios.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/include/uapi/linux/sockios.h#L128) for latest v3.10.y kernel as of today.
For newer kernel it's still there.

The necessary structure and enumeration values are defined in [include/uapi/linux/net_tstamp.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/include/uapi/linux/net_tstamp.h#L80).

Comment: Thanks. I'm also getting undeclared identifier for HWTSTAMP_FILTER_ALL and incomplete type struct hwtstamp_config. Are there additional headers I now require? I assumed it would all be in sockios.h